# Как найти строки в файлах и изменить их с помощью python?

Tags: python

Подскажите, есть файлы с логами app.log.gz, которые лежат в /2022/месяц/год/, 
в логе нужно найти запись 'PASS" => '(3 случайных числа)', как пример 'PASS' => '564', нужно заменить случайные трехзначные числа на *** , чтобы получилось так 'PASS' => '***' 
скрипт должен пробежаться по всем файлам в папках 
в Python не силен, сделал начало скрипта, но застрял на re.search() как через него найти 'PASS' => '3 случайных числа', так же попробовал задать re.search(r'[0-9][0-9][0-9]' выводится только одна запись в логе

```
import os.path
import gzip
import re


for root, dirs, files in os.walk("2022"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('app.log.gz'):
            path_file = os.path.join(root, file)
            with gzip.open(path_file, 'rb') as oldfile:
                oldfile = str(oldfile.read())
                data = re.search(r'[0-9][0-9][0-9]', str(oldfile))
                print(data)
                вывод <re.Match object; span=(16, 19), match='202'>

                #with gzip.open(path_file + 'new', 'w') as newfile:
                #    newfile.write(oldfile).
```

Comment: re.search находит только первое совпадение. Используй re.findall() (и читай документацию)

Comment: Если это Unix, то задача решается в одну строку с помощью `find`, `sed`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо, сделал через find, sed